# From abstract to concrete complex projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

By definition, a(n abstract) complex projective variety $X$ has an expression $E$ (many actually) of the form $\bigcap_i V_i$, with each $V_i$ a hypersurface in a ${\Bbb P}^m$ ($m$ depending on $E$).  Each $V_i$ has its degree, so one may associate to $E$ the multiset of these degrees.  The family of all multisets that arise as $E$ varies manifestly consititutes an invariant, call it ${\cal H}_X$, of $X$.

**How can one calculate ${\cal H}_X$ from familiar invariants of $X$ (e.g. cohomology)?**

**What closure properties do families ${\cal H}_X$ necessarily possess?**

Comment: A few quick comments: (a) This depends on the choice of embedding into
projective space. So it's not an invariant of $X$ alone. (b) It is
more natural to consider the ideal of polynomials vanishing along $X$.

Comment: @Donu I don't understand.  I intended my ${\cal H}_X$ to vary over all embeddings into projective space.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood.

Comment: If I understand well, the invariant $H_X$ determines $X$ up to isomorphism (as an abstract variety). I don't understand what it would mean to determine $X$ up to isomorphy from familiar invariants. 

Comment: This will not be so well-behaved for embeddings where $X$ is not a complete intersection. When it is, you can extract that multiset from the Hilbert polynomial of $X$. The set of Hilbert polynomials of line bundles of $X$ can be described using Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch and the intersection theory on $X$. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I doubt that my ${\cal H}_X$ determines $X$ up to isomorphism: suspect that ${\cal H}_X$ functions as a de facto discrete invariant insensitive to moduli. And I never asked about determining $X$ up to isomorphism, only ${\cal H}_X$.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I misread the definition (I thought the hypersurfaces were elements of the multisets). 

Comment: @Will  Yes, please.  Posting I didn't know whether this was a mere exercise for an expert or an open problem.  Evidently a little of both.  And please say something more about the not a complete intersection story.